# Updating a bag exception

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have database tables like this:

[tblRecord]

```
RecordId    MyColumn1   MyColumn2  
----------------------------------
112         somedata8   somedata7   
112         somedata6   somedata1   
148         somedata3   somedata5
```

[tblRecordFruit]

```
RecordId    FruitTypeId  
-------------------------
  112         53  
  112         85  
  148         16
```

[tblFruitType]

```
FruitTypeId     Text  
----------------------
53              Apple  
85              Banana  
16              Orange
```

And corresponding NHibernate mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
    <class name="Record, Infrastructure.Interface"
           table="tblRecord">
        <id name="Id" type="Int32" unsaved-value="null">
            <column name="RecordId" length="4" sql-type="int" not-null="true" unique="true" index="PK_tblRecord" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        ...
        <bag name="Fruits" table="tblRecordFruit" inverse="false" lazy="true" cascade="save-update">
            <key>
                <column name="RecordId" length="4" sql-type="int" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <many-to-many
                class="FruitType, Infrastructure.Interface">
                <column name="FruitTypeId" length="2" sql-type="smallint" not-null="true" />
            </many-to-many>
        </bag>
        ...
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="FruitType, Infrastructure.Interface"
         table="tblFruitType"
         mutable="false"
         lazy="false">
    <id name="Id" type="Int16" unsaved-value="0">
      <column name="FruitTypeID" sql-type="smallint" not-null="true" unique="true" index="PK_Fruit" />
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="Text" type="String">
      <column name="Text" length="255" sql-type="varchar" not-null="true" />
    </property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And C# code using NHiberate to get and `Save`/`SaveOrUpdate`/`Merge` the data:

```
public Interface.SortableBindingList<T> GetByCriteria (NHibernate.ICriteria criteria)
{
    System.Collections.Generic.IList<T> myList = criteria.List<T>();
    SortableBindingList<T> mySortableList = ConvertToGenericBindingList(myList);
    return mySortableList;
}

using (NHibernate.ITransaction tx = this.session.BeginTransaction())
{
    // this.session.Save (this.Record);
    // this.session.SaveOrUpdate (this.Record);
    this.session.Merge(this.Record);
    tx.Commit(); // Exception here
}
```

So user creates a record (or opens a record that has no `FruitTypes`) and adds some fruit types and then saves. All is well.

Then the user opens that record again and adds another `FruitType` to it. 
The `Record` class has a Collection defined:

```
public virtual System.Collections.Generic.IList<FruitType> Fruits
```

And a Fruit is added like so:

```
Record.Fruits.Add(fruitType);
```

On saving it, this exception is thrown:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_tblRecordFruit_1'.
>   Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.tblRecordFruit'. The duplicate key value is (112, 53).

It appears to be inserting another row `(112,53)` into `tblRecordFruit` instead of updating it.  Any data in `tblRecord` in `MyColumn1` or `MyColumn2` is updated just fine.

As you can see in the C# code, I've tried `.Save()`, `.SaveOrUpdate()`, and `.Merge()`, and all cause the same exception.

NHibernate Version 4.0.0.4000

How do I do this?

Comment: Thanks for editing the question. Something else I should have said, in retrospect: I think this is due to an upgrade from NHibernate v2 to v4. This upgrade occurred a couple years ago, but this error was not noticed until now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are trying to update `Record` object disconnected from session. And so you use `Merge` for session re-connection.

In this case to make `Merge` work for your collections they need `merge` cascade option in mapping. So try to update your `Fruits` mapping with:
`cascade="merge,save-update"` or simply with `cascade="all"` to cover all cases:

```xml
<bag name="Fruits" table="tblRecordFruit" inverse="false" lazy="true" cascade="all">
```

P.S. `SaveOrUpdate` call should actually work properly with your existing `Fruits` mapping `cascade="save-update"`. Maybe you've tried it before updating mapping otherwise please make sure that exception is the same and provide also mapping for `Fruit`.

**Update 1** So as previously stated I assume that you are trying to update detached entity (entity loaded from different session). Please confirm it and provide details how exactly it happens? Is it serialized/de-serialized from state that is shown on UI?

In this case you should be aware that you need to serialize state after object is saved. Because after save `Fruits` collection type is changed to internal NHibernate collection that is required for proper handling of further updates. So when `record.Fruits.Add(obj)` is called for existing `Record` object `record.Fruits` must not be of `List<T>` type it should be some NHibernate  type (supposedly `PersistangGenericType<T>`).

So please make sure you are not overwriting collection properties for existing objects:

```
record.Fruits = new List<FruitType>();// WRONG for existing record...

//Instead clear existing record collection:
record.Fruits.Clear(); //Correct
```

Also make the following checks in debugger:

```
//You somehow obtain record instance that you want to update
var record = DeserializeOrLoadState(recordId);

...//When you update existing record
record.Fruits.Add(fruitType1);// Make sure in debugger that for existing record record.Fruits is NHibernate type PesistentGenericBag<T> and not List<T>

...//When you SaveOrUpdate/Merge existing record
session.Merge(record);// <- make sure in debugger that for existing record.Fruits is NHibernate type PesistentGenericBag<T> and not List<T>

...
SerializeState(record);// serialize state only after session.SaveOrUpdate
```

**Update 2**

> It is not a PersistentGenericBag. This used to work. Is it possible that a change from NHibernate v2 to v4 now causes this problem?

I don't know how it was done in NHibernate v2 - but surely it can be fixed in your code. So you need to investigate why it's still `List` - it indicates that you are doing something wrong.
Some suggestions:

1) If you have setter for your `Fruits` property -  remove it to make sure all manipulations are done via `IList` methods:

```
public class Record
{
    public virtual IList<FruitType> Fruits {get; } = new List<FruitType>()
}
```

2) Investigate this part `Then the user opens that record again and adds another FruitType to it.`. You still didn't say how it's implemented. How's UI <-> Entity mapping is implemented here? When existing entity is loaded from DB I'm pretty sure it's not `List` and of NHibernate type. So you should debug and find the place why it's changed to `List`.

3) Also try to change cascade setting to `cascade="all-delete-orphan"`. I don't think it would change anything - but just in case.

Comment: The exception occurs using these 2 lines: `<bag name="Fruits" table="tblRecordFruit" inverse="false" lazy="true" cascade="all">` and `this.Record = this.session.Merge(this.Record);`

Comment: `System.Collections.Generic.IList<FruitType> Fruits` ... It is not a `PersistentGenericBag`. This used to work. Is it possible that a change from NHibernate v2 to v4 now causes this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The exception:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_tblRecordFruit_1'.
>   Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.tblRecordFruit'. The duplicate key value is (112, 53).

says there is violation of primary key constraint. That means you are attempting to duplicate the value of primary key column.

Looking at following block of code in your mappings:

```
<bag name="Fruits" table="tblRecordFruit" inverse="false" lazy="true" cascade="save-update">
    <key>
        <column name="RecordId" length="4" sql-type="int" not-null="true" />
    </key>
```

it seems that `RecordId` is your primary key on `tblRecordFruit` table. If this is the case, it is obvious that you cannot insert the sample data you mentioned in your question into the  table:

> ```
> RecordId    FruitTypeId
> -----------------------
>   112         53
>   112         85
>   148         16
> ```

The value `112` cannot repeat in column `RecordId`. If your code is attempting to do that, it is obvious that you will get the exception that you said.

Are you looking for [composite key](https://nhibernate.info/blog/2010/06/30/nhibernate-and-composite-keys.html) (on both `RecordId` and `FruitTypeId` columns) instead?

> First, a caveat: composite keys are certainly mappable in NHibernate, but it's a little trickier than a typical single identity key would be.  Compared to a normal key, there's some extra setup work, queries are more painful, and they tend to be less optimized in terms of lazy loading. Because of these things, experienced NHibernate users often avoid composite keys entirely when possible.
>   ....
>   ....
>
> ```
> <composite-id>
>     <key-many-to-one class="SuperShop.Domain.OrderItemComponent,SuperShop.Domain" name="OrderItemComponent" column="OrderItemProductID" />
>     <key-property name="DetailType" column="DetailTypeID" type="SuperShop.Domain.DetailTypes,SuperShop.Domain" />
> </composite-id>
> <version name="LastModifiedOn"....
> ```

Comment: `The value 112 cannot repeat in column RecordId` Error clearly says that key consists of 2 values: `The duplicate key value is (112, 53)`. It's correct many-to-many mapping